# Netsuite: Download XML Response via API

Tags: c#, xml, netsuite

Background: relatively new to C# and NetSuite.

Given a little netsuite method (via SuiteTalk) such as:

```
private void getInvoice()
{
    RecordRef invoiceRef = new RecordRef
    {
        internalId = "111111",
        type = RecordType.invoice,
        typeSpecified = true
    };

    ReadResponse readResponse = _service.get(invoiceRef);

}//eof
```

How would I get the entirety of the readResponse as a file? It is an XML file on the front-end...can I download / read that to a file at the end of this script? I don't know if its being treated as a stream here or not either, which would make it a little easier to just turn it into a file.

Comment: Is the response a stream or a string :            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(stream);
            doc.LoadXml(string);
            doc.Save(filename);

Answer (score 0):

In your example, a request would be made to NetSuite and the response will be loaded into your "readResponse" variable as a ReadResponse class.  You would then need to convert the record returned into an Invoice:

```
Invoice invoiceRecord = (Invoice)readResponse.record;
```

if you want to write the response to a file, you could do something like this:

```
        ReadResponse readResponse = _service.get(invoiceRef);
        FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("response.xml");
        XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReadResponse));
        writer.Serialize(fs, readResponse);
        fs.Close();
```